# Can't compile nginx::source

Tags: chef, chef-solo

I have downloaded nginx cookbook  manually today from http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/nginx and started it with 
`include_recipe nginx::source`, using chef-solo 11.4 on Ubuntu 12.04

But I have got an error

`/nginx/recipes/source.rb line: 28`

`28>> nginx_url = node['nginx']['source']['url'] ||    "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-#{node['nginx']['source']['version']}.tar.gz"`

and the errors are:

```
`
[2013-05-07T18:54:38+04:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-05-07T18:54:38+04:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
[2013-05-07T18:54:39+04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-05-07T18:54:39+04:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
`
```

How to fix it?

Comment: First look at the "stack trace" to see if you can determine what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting the attributes

```
node["nginx"]["source"]["url"]
```

and/or

```
node["nginx"]["source"]["version"]
```

It seems as if one of those doesn't exist, which is strange, since they're set up with defaults in the cookbook.

If this doesn't help, please respond with as much information as you can. There's usually a bit more detailed info further up the scrollback, as it only displays the error summary at the end.